# Do corporations outside of the Eurozone issue bonds in Euro?

Tags: bonds

Do corporate issuers outside of the Eurozone (as in the wider EU area, or non-EU countries) issue bonds in Euros (EUR)? How relatively common is this, compared to issuing bonds in USD, if you are a non-US and non-Eurozone debtor?

Would that qualify for what's referred to as "Euro denominated" bonds, or does that simply mean that the price of the bond is listed/represented in EUR?

---

Note that I'm *not* referring to so called "Eurobonds" which is something different:

> A Eurobond is an international bond that is denominated in a currency
>   not native to the country where it is issued. Also called external
>   bond; "external bonds which, strictly, are neither Eurobonds nor
>   foreign bonds […]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by @Wecon in the comments:

> With respect to your first question: they certainly do. The BIS quarterly review of sept. 2015 (p.9) even shows that "firms in the United States increasingly issued euro-denominated debt to benefit from the low borrowing costs." This may already be a set-up for answering your second question: its (relative) importance may be highly dependent on economic circumstances